# Plotting in R using Java - works, but cannot find the plot

Tags: java, r, runtime.exec

I am trying to invoke some r code from within Java,pretty much like this:

```
private void makeMatrix() throws ScriptException {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" Rscript firstscript.r");
        System.out.println("Script executed");
         } catch (IOException ex) {
       System.out.println("Exception");
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Well, I get the "Script executed" print.

My (well, not really mine, just to test)  r-Code is fairly simple, pretty much just to see it works at all:

```
x=seq(0,2,by=0.01)
y=2*sin(2*pi*(x-1/4))
plot(x,y)
```

So, it should not do much more than plot a sinus.

However, should not there be some kind of popup where you can actually see the plot?
because there is none. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: In response to the comments I got here I edited the r-file, adding:

```
jpeg('rplot.jpg')
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

to it.

However, If I then try to find rplot.jpg on my system it simply is not there.

Comment: You should probably explicitly declare a new device for the plot. On OSX the function is `quartz`, on Windows it is `windows`, on *nix I believe you want `X11`. It may make more sense to save the plot to a file using, e.g., `png` and then open the file from Java.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) or [Rcaller](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php), the latter of which has explicit plotting support rather than manually invoking the R executable.

Comment: I had a look at both of them. The problem is, the jar has to be executable on windows AND linux, and I simply did not manage that with either.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: I would be happy enough if I got an error message or an exception, but how can it be that I get my print but the file I made in the rscript is not on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed a relative directory to the `jpeg` function .  This makes it relative to R's current working directory (the value returned by `getwd`).

Try printing this value to see where that is (on Windows, by default it's in "My Documents" for the current user)

```
print(getwd())
```

or passing an absolute path to `jpeg`.

```
jpeg('c:/rplot.jpg')
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

---

To get an absolute path, use `pathological::standardize_path` or `R.utils::getAbsolutePath`.

Comment: That seems to be the Problem. However, how do I find this absolute path (without again using runtime.exec)? I suppose depending on the computer the user uses to open the jar, the script (bundled within the jar) will be in another folder too, won't it?

Comment: I have got a weird idea....I could actually as soon as the user starts the program create those r-scripts on the users computer. I guess that would work, but is this solution sensible?

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the `Process` (`exec` returns a `Process` object) to finish
with `waitFor`, and check the exit value: it should be 0.

If it is not zero, you probably need to specify the path of the script.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript /tmp/test.R");
    System.out.println("Started");
    p.waitFor();
    if( p.exitValue() != 0 )
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    else 
        System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

If the exit value is not 0, you can look at the stdout and stderr of the process,
as suggested in Andrew's comment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("test...");
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
        "Rscript",
        "-e",
        "print(rnorm(5)))" // Intentional error, to produce an error message
    } );
    System.out.println("Started");

    String line = null;

    System.out.println("Stdout:");
    BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( p.getInputStream() ) );
    while ( (line = stdout.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);

    System.out.println("Stderr:");
    BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( p.getErrorStream() ) );
    while ( (line = stderr.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);

    p.waitFor();
    if( p.exitValue() != 0 )
        System.out.println("Something went wrong, exit value=" + p.exitValue());
    else 
        System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

As mentionned in the comments, 
you need to explicitly open the device.
Since it is closed when the script terminates, you also need to add a delay.

```
x11() # Open a device (also works on Windows)
plot( rnorm(10) )
Sys.sleep(10) # Wait 10 seconds
```

Comment: `device` refers to the type of graphical output, e.g., a window, a PNG file, a PDF file, etc. `x11()` and `windows()` are equivalent and open a window to display the plots. Check `?device`.

Comment: Sometimes I could just..... I know there is no mistake in my r-skript because the exact same script works when used via command line. I know the absolute path is correkt and I STILL get started/sth wrong. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Follow Andrew's advice, in the comments above, 
and print the standard output and standard error of the process: 
you will know what goes wrong.
I have updated my answer accordingly.